# Gulp watch task for sass file doesn't watch the sass file

Tags: sass, gulp

I have setup all the required configuration for sass:watch task, but when i start the invoking the watch task, it doesn't watch the sass file task and so no compiling the sass to css file

Here is my gulp file,

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync');

    gulp.task('sass', function () {
        return gulp.src('./css/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
    });

    gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
        gulp.watch('./css/*.scss', ['sass']);
    });

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
        var files = [
            './*.html',
            './css/*.css',
            './img/*.{png,jpg,gif}',
            './js/*.js'
        ];

        browserSync.init(files, {
            server: {
            baseDir: "./"
            }
        });

    });

    // Default task
    gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync'), function() {
        gulp.start('sass:watch');
    });
```

Is any problem with task with of default ?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, please try this:

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('browser-sync', 'sass:watch'));
```

I suppose, with "parallel", these tasks could be implemented at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try this instead:

```
// Default task
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('browser-sync', 'sass:watch'));
```

`gulp.start` isn't going to work in gulp v4.  Plus your `default` task had three arguments, only two are allowed.

Comment: still the sass:watch task are not being watching the sass file, same problem still pending.. please can you explain in detail.